# Print the following pattern for n number of rows. For eg. N = 5 1 1 12 21 123 321 1234 4321 1234554321

Tags: python

I'm doing this question but the code I wrote gives the same output with different spacing.

This is what I wrote:

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j,end='')
    for j in range(0,2*n-2*i):
        print(" ",end='')
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print(j,end='')
```

The output seems to be a little different then what is actually expected.

My output:

```
1        112      21123    3211234  43211234554321
```

Expected output:

```
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

As I see it, with every iteration of the first for loop, we are not jumping into a new line. Why is it so? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is a small mistake. You should add a newline printing at the last of your for loop.

Try this:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        print(j,end='')
    for j in range(0,2*n-2*i):
        print(" ",end='')
    for j in range(i,0,-1):
        print(j,end='')
    print('')
```

Tested output:

> ```
> 1        1
> 12      21
> 123    321
> 1234  4321
> 1234554321
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please explain me what exactly is the new line printing in python? I thought that with every iteration the for loop will automatically switch to next line.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but I guess because of using nested for loops, we may need to print newline character explicitly to get a newline

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @amrs-tech, you should add a print() at the end of i-loop to get a newline, and the following also works:

```
def pattern(n):
   agg = ""
   for i in range(1, n+1):
      agg = "".join((agg, str(i))
      print(agg, 2*(n-i)*' ', agg[::-1]
```

This is a minimial solution.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution:

```
def pattern(n, current=1):
    if current > n:
        return
    r = ''.join(map(str, range(1, current+1)))
    print('{: <{width}}{: >{width}}'.format(r, r[::-1], width=n))
    pattern(n, current+1)

pattern(5)
```

Prints:

```
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

---

Or without recursion:

```
def pattern(n):
    for current in range(2, n+2):
        r = ''.join(map(str, range(1, current)))
        print('{: <{width}}{: >{width}}'.format(r, r[::-1], width=n))

pattern(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a the newline being printed at the end of the outer for loop.

Alternate solution with list comprehensions:

```py
>>> n=5
>>> for i in range(1,n):
...     print(
...         ''.join([str(x) for x in range(1,i+1)])
...         + ' '*2*(n-i-1)
...         + ''.join([str(x) for x in range(i,0,-1)])
...     )
... 
1      1
12    21
123  321
12344321
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input('Enter number: '))
for i in range(n):
    print(''.join(map(str,range(1,i+2))) + ' '*2*(n-i-1) + ''.join(map(str,range(i+1,0,-1))))
```

Output:

```
Enter number: 5
1        1
12      21
123    321
1234  4321
1234554321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input( ))
i = 1
while i <= n:
    j = 1
    while j <= i:
        print(j, end="")
        j += 1

    spaces = 1
    while spaces <= n - i:
        print(" ", end="")
        spaces += 1

    space = 1
    while space <= n - i:
        print(" ", end="")
        space += 1

    j = 1
    p = i
    while j <= i:
        print(p,end="")
        j += 1
        p -= 1
    print()
    i += 1
```

## Easy and Clean but not optimised

Comment: Hey CUD, welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be beneficial if you could explain the code in your answer and how you think it differs from the years of existing answers to this question.